# Can't close 3rd party ad content in Selenide

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenide, google-advertising-id

can you please suggest what I need to do to close this advertising in my  project, I used Selenide to find elements, of the advertising at the end of the scenario I had closed it, but I can't close it before the scenario, and I don't know why, I think I found correct element, but smth wrong with it, maybe my approach to working with advertising is a little off, if not wrong at all, here what code I have

```
@Test
    public void SignOnFlow()  {
        if (Vignette.GoogleVignetteBigButton.isDisplayed()){
            Vignette.GoogleVignetteBigButton.click();
        }
        else{
            System.out.printf("No add were displayed");
        }
        headerRegionStart.SignOn.click();
        singOnButtons.UserNameField.sendKeys("UserTestName");
        singOnButtons.Password.sendKeys("password");
        singOnButtons.Submit.click();
        SelenideElement RegistrationForm = $x("//a[contains(text(),'registration')]");
        RegistrationForm.shouldBe();
        assertEquals(RegistrationForm.shouldBe(),RegistrationForm,"Check if ResgisrationForm is visible");
        MercuryToursPage.Home.click();
        if (Vignette.GoogleVignetteButton.isDisplayed()){
            Vignette.GoogleVignetteButton.click();

        }
        else Selenide.screenshot("AllureScreen2");
    }
```

This part found the button and close the advertising

```
if (Vignette.GoogleVignetteButton.isDisplayed()){
            Vignette.GoogleVignetteButton.click();

        }
else Selenide.screenshot("AllureScreen2");
```

but this is NOT working

```
if (Vignette.GoogleVignetteBigButton.isDisplayed()){
            Vignette.GoogleVignetteBigButton.click();
        }
        else{
            System.out.printf("No add were displayed");
        }
```

This what is locators for this elements

```
public static SelenideElement GoogleVignetteButton = $x("//div[@id='dismiss-button']");
    

public static SelenideElement GoogleVignetteBigButton = $x("//div[@class='ns-c6pru-e-16 button-common close-button']");
```

This what kind of ad I'm trying to close

[image]

I'm trying to close 3rd party ad, but nothing works

Comment: What is your problem statement? it looks a bit unclear, please make exact and clear

Comment: I have a test in Selenium before it starts, and an advertising banner pops up for me, and I need to close it, this is the whole problem, I tried to close this banner, but I can’t find the element.

PS: then I also have an advertising banner at the end of the test and I can close it, but with the first one I have problems, why such a problem idk, that's what I'm asking for